# Symfony2 - Doctrine2 store changeset for later (or alternative solution to approve changes)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, changeset

I have several entities, each with its form type. I want to be able, instead of saving the entity straight away on save, to save a copy of the changes we want to perform and store it in DB.
We'd send a message to the user who can approve the change, who will review the original and the changed field(s) and will approve or not. If approved the entity would be properly flushed.

To solve the issue I was thinking about:

1) doing a persist

2) getting the changesets (both the one related to "normal" fields, and the one relative to collections)

3) storing it in DB

4) Performing $em->refresh() to discard changes.

Later what I need is to get the changset(s) back, ask the (other) user to approve it and flush it.

Is this doable? What I'm especially concerned about is that the entity manager that generated the first changeset is not the same we are going to use to perform the flush, I basically need to "load" a changeset.

Any idea on how to solve the issue (this way, or another way ;) )

Another solution (working only for "normal" fields, not reference ones that come from other entities to the current one, like a many to many) would be to clone the current entity, store it, and then once approved copy the field(s) from the cloned to the original one. But it does not work for all fields (if the previous solution does not work we'd limit the feature just to "normal" fields).

Thank you!

SN

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just treat the modifications as entities themselves, so that every change is stored in the database, and then all the changes that were approved are executed against the entity.

So, for example, if you have some `Book`s stored in the database, and you want to make sure that all the modifications made to these are approved, just add a model that would contain the changeset that has to be processed, and a handler that would apply these changes:

```
<?php

class UpdateBookCommand
{
    // If you'll store these commands in a database, perhaps this field would be a relation,
    // or you could just store the ID
    public $bookId;

    public $newTitle;

    public $newAuthor;

    // Perhaps this field should be somehow protected from unauthorized changes
    public $isApproved;
}

class UpdateBookHandler
{
    private $bookRepository;

    private $em;

    public function handle(UpdateBookCommand $command)
    {
        if (!$command->isApproved) {
            throw new NotAuthorizedException();
        }

        $book = $this->bookRepository->find($command->bookId);
        $book->setTitle($command->newTitle);
        $book->setAuthor($command->newAuthor);

        $this->em->persist($book);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

Next, in your controller you would just have to make sure that the commands are somehow stored (in a database or maybe even in a message queue), and the handler gets called when the changesets could possibly get applied.

P.S. Perhaps I could have explained this a bit better, but mostly the inspiration for this solution comes from the [CQRS pattern that's explained quite well by Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html). However, I guess in your case a full-blown CQRS implementation is unnecessary and a simpler solution should work.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! It's not directly applicable as we have several entities and I need a general purpose solution, but it helped me thinking. I'll post the  definitive solution when I come up with one ;)